# CSS-only ProgressBar with gradient color that highlights current status

Tags: css, progress-bar

I was looking for CSS-only **ProgressBar** that shows such activity with a nice looking using gradients and animations.

I investigated `<progress>` tag but it's [very limited in styling](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/), so I looked for other solutions but I was able to find only static examples, or in which [gradients are contracted within limits](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/) of lowest advance statuses, or in other case a complex markup with many nested `DIV`.

Desiderata should be:

- CSS-only solution
- Gradient background
- Gradient should not be collapsed if progressbar is less than 100% of its completition
- Animated status
- Minimal markup

Could be interesting if it could have also an *inderterminate* status.

Answer (score 6):

You can use one element and simplify your code like below:

```css
.progressbar {
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin:5px;
    background: 
      linear-gradient(-45deg,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%,transparent 25%, 
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%,transparent 75%) 
      left/30px 30px repeat-x,
      linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, yellow 50%, green 100%) left/var(--p,100%) fixed,
      lightgray;
  box-shadow:inset 0px -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  animation: change 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes change {
  from {background-position:0 0,left}
  to {background-position:30px 0,left}
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar" style="width:80%;"></div>
<div class="progressbar" style="width:20%;"></div>
<div class="progressbar" style="width:90%;"></div>
<div class="progressbar" style="--p:0"></div>
<div class="progressbar" style="--p:0;width:60%;"></div>
<div class="progressbar" style="--p:0;width:30%;"></div>
```

Comment: I know, but is not the same result. In my version, end point is rounded and animating zebras end with the colored bar, without a background for the remaining part. Anywaym it could surely be an interesting solution for someone. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @LucaDetomi in this case it's easier ;) check the update ... I kept the CSS variable but you can remove it

Comment: Very close, but you missed "indeterminate" status that I described :-) Anyway, great job

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any existing solution that correspond to all desiderata so I developed a [possible solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/3su9yczw/59/).

**HTML**

Markup is simply (for [*indeterminate* status](https://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/3su9yczw/59/)):

```
<div class="progressbar"></div>
```

or (for a [specific advancement status](https://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/3su9yczw/61/))

```
<div class="progressbar" style="width:75%"></div>
```

The idea is that advancement status is set via JS during process with a simple instruction such as (in jQuery):

```
$('.progressbar').width('75%')
```

**CSS**

For CSS part, apart cosmetich properties, the interesting thing is the use of generated content on `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to avoid additional markup, respectively to contain colored gradient and overlap zebra animated bars.

To allows gradient to be gradually shown increasing ProgressBar widh, original container has `overflow:hidden` property.

Finally, to have *indeterminate* status, background-color is forced in case style attribute is empty or missing.

```
.progressbar:not([style]):before,
.progressbar[style='']:before{
   background: lightgray;
}
```

Comment: Please, feel free to suggest other improvements to this solution