# Showing part of the box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show only part of the entire box.

```
<div class="box">30%</div>
```

```
.box{
    background : linear-gradient(to right, rgba(250,0,0,0),rgba(250, 0, 0, 1));
}
```

The box looks like this, and I want to make only 30% of the background of the box colored and the rest transparent. I'm not trying to minimize the box to 30% width. I want the box's width to stay 100% but show only 30% of the gradient background.

Answer (score 1):

##### If you wanna do it with the css background property, here you go:

```css
background: background: linear-gradient(270deg, #F00 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.473958) 70.00%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 70.01%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
```

This is how it'll look line in a white background:
[image]

Notice the "70%" standing right there, it's where you can control where in the dimension you want a color to start (in this case rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) at 70% from the right border) 
You can read more about it at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()#gradient_with_multi-position_color_stops

Comment: Sorry, I think my question wasn't clear enough... For example, if my box is a rainbow, what I'm trying to make is a box that is colored until orange, and leaves the rest of the rainbow white. But your answer is like a rainbow that is squashed in 30% width and leaves the rest of the box white.

Comment: let me see if I understood correctly, what you wanna do is something like this: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/852265957802901545/871095905988792400/unknown.png ?
If yes, I'll edit my answer explaining how to do it

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/871096646598017027/871096872666796042/20210801_032749.png
I'm trying to show the left 30% of the entire box and change the background color of the right 70% to white... I'm sorry, but I'm really bad at explaining =(

Comment: Did I get it right now?
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/852265957802901545/871098423485546516/unknown.png
Don't worry, we all have been trough it

Comment: Thanks for comforting me! What I'm trying to do is to leave the left side of the box and color the right side of the box in white.  https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/871096646598017027/871098396591665192/20210801_033333.png

Comment: Just edited it, I believe I got it right this time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235492/discussion-between-pedro-henrique-and-).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are wanting to have the left 70% transparent and have the gradient show only for the last 30%. If this is what you want you need to add `70%` to your first colour stop as follows:

```css
#box1{
    background : linear-gradient(to right, rgba(250,0,0,0) 70%,rgba(250, 0, 0, 1));
}

#box2{
    background : linear-gradient(to left, red, orange 70%, rgba(250,0,0,0) 30%);
}

#box3{
    background : linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, orange 30%, white 30% );
}


.box {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1">30%</div>

<div class="box" id="box2">30%</div>

<div class="box" id="box3">30%</div>
```

It looks like the OP was looking for something similar to a rainbow progress bar. There are many examples available including this one here: [Progress bar different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61842069/progress-bar-different-colors)

Comment: Sorry, I think my question wasn't clear enough... For example, if my box is a rainbow, what I'm trying to make is a box that is colored until orange, and leaves the rest of the rainbow white. But your answer is like a rainbow that is squashed in 30% width and leaves the rest of the box white.

Comment: @김규민 So I think you just need to add more color stops in then.

Comment: @김규민 I have updated my answer with a box2, run the code snippet to see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I think you just need to apply background radient and than use ::before or after to cover rest 70% area of the box.

Comment: @kojow7 Actually, what I'm trying to do is to leave the left side of the box and color the right side of the box in white. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/871096646598017027/871098396591665192/20210801_033333.png

Comment: @Nikkkshit I think this might work, but I can't figure out how to...=(

Comment: check my answer I have added box4

Comment: @김규민 I have now added a third box, let me know what you think.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to make, but I can't figure out how to apply that to the first box...=(

Comment: @김규민 I am confused by what you mean, what's the difference whether it's in the first box or the third box? You just change the code to match. Notice that I use both "id" and "class" if that's throwing you off. But you can just copy the background line from #box3 into your .box code.

Comment: @김규민 Another option if you want something similar to a progress bar is in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956798/css-only-progressbar-with-gradient-color-that-highlights-current-status

Comment: The rainbow was just a metaphor, what I meant was that I want to chop off any random place in the middle of the rainbow so that it ends in a random color, like orange or yellow, not purple.

Comment: Yeah, I think that link was what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: @김규민 Yay!!! You are very welcome. Just do a search for CSS rainbow progress bar to get other examples that you might like better. Here is another one: https://codepen.io/internette/pen/QNOeLo - I also added a link at the end of my answer to another similar one on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Youn Can acheive it by:

- css gradient background generator
- with ::before and ::after
- with clippath

```css
span{
  color:blue;
}
.box{
  height:100px;
background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 30%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 30%);
}
.box2{
  margin-top:30px;
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
}
.box2::before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#000;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:30%;
  z-index:-1;
}
.box3{
  background-color:#000;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:15px;
  clip-path: inset(0 70% 0 0);
}
.box4{
  margin-top:15px;
position:relative; 
height:100px;
background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
.box4::before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:70%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>content<span>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <span>content<span>
</div>
<div class="box3">
  <span>width clip path</span>
</div>
    <div class="box4">
    <span>As per your comment</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hmm... box 1, 2, 3 looks black, and box 4 was just an example, but I think it's a bit different from what I want... What I'm trying to make looks kind of like this reversed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXAXn.png

Comment: check the first box

Comment: I found what I was looking for! Thanks for answering!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956798/css-only-progressbar-with-gradient-color-that-highlights-current-status